# How can I see what specific library dll files my QT application needs to create an installer?

Tags: windows, qt

Honestly, the QT documentation out there is really scarce, and the ones that do exist barely touch on this topic.

All I want to do is create an installer for my QT application. I have been watching and reading some documentation on the QT Installer Framework, and some on NSIS as well. The part I am trying to figure out is how I identify the dll files I need?

On linux there is `ldd` which solves this problem. What is there on Windows? Is there anything?

I am using QT Cretor 4.11.0 and QT 5.13.0 with MSVC 2017.

Comment: There is an old and good `ldd` equivalent for Windows - the Dependency Walker. It can show all dependencies required for your binary (dll or exe).

Answer (score 0):

The docs are fine IMO, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html Check `windeployqt` tool mentioned there. You may also use DependencyWalker tool https://www.dependencywalker.com/.